# UIScrollView not active when zoom

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

My problem are:

1. I implement a UIScrollView (DrawView)to draw something on it(Task is ok).
2. I drag a ScrollView to ViewController using storyboard and assign DrawView class to it.
3. I using pink gesture to zoom one element in DrawView, it is correct, but when element out of size DrawView i cant scroll it to see part of element.

In file ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.drawingView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.drawingView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 200)];
}
```

Can you give me way to solution problem or some tutorial same?
Thank for all

Sorry for bad grammar

Comment: what is size of drawingView?

Comment: size of drawingView is 700x900

Answer (score 0):

Set content size of the scrollView as the size of the element which you are adding to it.

Say elementView is the view that you are adding to scroll view then,

```
[self.drawingView setContentSize:elementView.size];
```

Comment: I try to it but problem not solution, even i change contentSize larger  elementView.size.

Comment: Try self.drawingView.frame = self.view.frame. If this don't solve your issue pls put the self.drawingView.frame and elemantView.size here

Comment: I posted detail in topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394616/uiscrollerview-not-active. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, drawingview size is 700x900 which is **less than** your content size 100 x 200. That's why, it couldn't get scroll. `Content size should be greater than size`, then only it will get scroll even scrolling enabled.